# Get built-in reads action for a specific namespace

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get all built-in read actions for a specific namespace but documentation and get code link in app config gives something like /me/news.reads which gives a list of all read actions on every namespace.

I tried /me/{namespace}:{action-type}/{object-type} but it's not working for built in actions.
Is there any way to directly query the built-in actions for a namespace or I need to sort and extract what interests me in the bulk result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that currently is to fetch all and locally filter the results.